# I can not get dates after my current date

Tags: mongodb

I want to obtain the records that the "FECHA_FIN" field is greater than or equal to today's date.

this is an example of my data:

[image]

but with this query:

```
db.getCollection('susp_programadas').find( {"FECHA_FIN":{ $gte: new Date("YYYY-mm-dd") }}  )
```

[image]
I do not get results, what am I doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date to an ISO date and query that way. Since you stored the date as a string mongo has no idea how to query it against an ISO date without conversion.

If you stored your date in mongo as the default ISO date then you could have easily done this:

```
db.getCollection('susp_programadas').find({"FECHA_FIN":{$gte: new Date()}})
```

So this is how you can do it now:

```
db.getCollection('susp_programadas').aggregate([
{
  $project: {
    date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: '$FECHA_FIN' }}
  }
  },
  { $match: { date: { $gte: new Date() }}}
])
```

You can use the [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) in an aggregate query with a `$match` to get the results you want. Note that $dateFromString is only available in **MongoDB version 3.6 and up**.

If there is no way to convert your data to ISODate or upgrade your DB you could also consider another solution which via [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/query/where/index.html):

```
db.getCollection('susp_programadas').find({
    $where: function(){
        return new Date(this.FECHA_FIN) > Date.now()
    }
})
```

However that solution suffers from the fact that `$where` **can not use indexes** so have that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am usin robomongo. I am getting this problem: https://i.imgur.com/XVxJTvI.png

Comment: What is your mongoDB version? `$dateFromString` is from 3.6 and above.

Comment: I see that it is 3.4. but I do not have permission in my work to update it, is there another way to achieve it?

Comment: The recommended approach would be to either update your data to `ISODate` or to upgrade your DB. I posted another solution which will not be performant and it is not by any means a best practice.

Comment: Failed to execute all of the script. The script has reached shell timeout (15 seconds) limit.